# copy down previous cells with 2 columns at once?

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

it is possible to copy down the values of cells, 2 columns at the same time (values are different in both columns = strings). Right now I am doing it separately.

1:

```
 Do Until ActiveCell.Row >= LastRow
        If Trim(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)) = "" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveCell
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
```

and then again for the 3rd column

```
    Cells(FirstRow + 2, 2).Select
  Do Until ActiveCell.Row >= LastRow
            If Trim(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)) = "" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveCell
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
```

Actually I coded this below, it goes simultaneously, but have an imporession that it is slow

```
Sub Kopi()
Dim i, y As Integer
For i = 1 To 100
    For y = 1 To 100
If Trim(Cells(i + 1, 1)) = "" And Trim(Cells(y + 1, 2)) = "" Then
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1)
    Cells(y + 1, 2).Value = Cells(y, 2)
    End If

Next y
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your data, and what you *expect* to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? It loops through your empty cells in the given range (`A1:B10`) and sets any blanks equal to the value above

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    For Each r In rng
        If Not r.Row = 1 Then r.Value = r.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    Next r
End Sub
```